# How to put text shaped hole in a rectangle

Tags: opengl

I have a HUD with a rectangle (glRect) on it. I want to be able to put a letter on it and see what's happening behind the rectangle but only where the text is rendered. Like putting a letter shaped hole in the rectangle.

Comment: Learn about using alpha component of the color (rectangle, text) and how to blend pixels. Pay attention to blending order and functions.

Comment: use stencil (GL_STENCIL_TEST) for that see: [I have an OpenGL Tessellated Sphere and I want to cut a cylindrical hole in it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39466130/2521214) or use transparency (GL_BLEND)