# OpenGL GL_DEPTH_TEST vs glDepthFunc and glDepthMask?

Tags: opengl, graphics, depth-buffer, zbuffer

I've been using `glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)` to disable depth testing, thinking that it only disables depth "testing". The reason I've been confused I guess is because I've created two functions, one to disable the depth "test", and another to disable depth "writes" with `glDepthMask(GL_FALSE);`

If disabling `GL_DEPTH_TEST` disables both "testing" and "writing" then would it be the equivalent of doing:

```
glDepthFunc(GL_ALWAYS​); // DISABLE TESTS (OR ACTUALLY ALWAYS LET THE TEST SUCCEED)
glDepthMask(GL_FALSE); // DISABLE WRITES
```

I'm thinking that there's little use for disabling `GL_DEPTH_TEST` unless I want to disable both tests and writes, and I'm wondering which one is better. The wording seems confusing, but maybe it's just me. I suppose doing disabling depth tests with `glDepthFun(GL_ALWAYS)` will still do a comparison, I suppose there's no way to disable the depth test entirely while still allowing writes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
```

turns off the Depth Test from pipeline. If you use:

```
glDepthFunc(GL_ALWAYS​);
glDepthMask(GL_FALSE);
```

instead it just hide it after condition (but still present in the pipeline) which could mean performance difference on some platforms ...

Also using your equivalent would need you to set/remember original `DepthFunc` in case you want to turn it on again (as there are many rendering techniques that need to switch the `DeptTest` on/off several times.

And lastly two **GL** function calls are bigger overhead than just one. So from performance point of view using `glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)` is better for this. The `glDepthFunc,glDepthMask` are intended for different purpose like multi pass rendering, [order independent transparency](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37783085/2521214),[holes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39466130/2521214), etc ...